# How to get clang-format to not remove trailing newline for function call?

Tags: objective-c, c, coding-style, clang-format

Currently I'm using a version of [this](https://github.com/haaakon/Apple-clang-format/blob/master/.clang-format) config, which is the closest I can find to idiomatic Obj-C formatting. However, it breaks the following convention, which is irritating enough to prevent me from turning on `clang-format` automatically:

```
@import AppKit;

int main() {
    // How can I get clang-format to respect this style?
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(
        0.f,
        0.f,
        100.f,
        200.f
    );

    NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromRect(NSRectFromCGRect(rect)));
}
```

Translates into:

```
@import AppKit;

int main() {
    // Right now it's formatted like this, which I do not want.
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(
        0.f,
        0.f,
        100.f,
        200.f);

    NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromRect(NSRectFromCGRect(rect)));
}
```

Is it possible to fix this?